# Python function to change data type of a column not working

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a python function to take in a column of a dataframe, check the data type and if it's false change to required data type. However, the changes happen only within the function. How to fix this to make permanent changes to the dataframe?

```
def change_required_data_type (column,data_type):
    is_correct = None

    for i in column:
        if type(i) != data_type:
            is_correct = False


    if is_correct != False:
        print('True')

    elif is_correct == False:
        column = column.astype(data_type)        
        print('False')
```

Comment: You've simply created a new series which is immediately discarded when the function terminates. You never modify the dataframe you pass in. As an aside, iterating over a series and checking the type of each object in it doesn't make much sense, the whole point of pandas is to have typed columns, so you should just check the `.dtype` of the column

Comment: i only pass in column for my function. So i need to modify it to pass in dataframe instead?

Comment: That would be a start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question of something only working inside a function and not outside, you need to add **return some object** to the end of your function.

```
def myfunc(column, data_type):
    # ...
    elif is_correct == False:
    column = column.astype(data_type)        
    print('False')

    # You've modified the column variable inside the function,
    # so your function needs to return it to outside the function.        
    return column

# Call your function from outside.
result = myfunc(column, data_type)  
# Use inputs for column and data_type when calling your function.
print(result)
```

However, if you are using Pandas library, you should use the conventional way to change datatype of a column.  See https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/09/how-to-change-data-type-for-one-or-more-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/

Generally, you want to use `df.astype(str)` to change the data type of one or more columns from a Pandas dataframe.  A single column of a dataframe is also called a Series.

```
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].astype('str')
df.Day = df.Day.astype('int64')
```

Here are some more examples of changing datatype in Pandas DataFrame object.

```
import pandas as pd

mydic = {
    "name": ['Alice', 'Tommy', 'Jane'],
    "age": [9, 21, 22],
    "height": [3.6, 6.1, 5.5],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = mydic)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

# First change age from integer to floating point.
df.age = df.age.astype('float64')

print(df.age)  # Notice the decimal format 9.0.
print(df.dtypes)  # age is now floating point.

# Next change height from floating point to integer.
df.height = df.height.astype('int32')
print(df.height)  # Notice height is truncated, no more decimal point.

# Next change age to string (object type).
df.age = df.age.astype('str')
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

# Change height from integer to float, using Bracket Notation.
df['height'] = df['height'].astype('float32')
print(df.dtypes)
# Notice height is a decimal format, 3.0.
# But the original fractional data of .6 was lost (was 3.6).
```

The default use of `df.astype('str')` is to return a COPY and not replace the original dataframe.  Because you have assigned the change to the original Series by using `df.name = ...` , you have changed the type "in-place".